# How to post HasMap's multiple values using Json

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on laundry app,in this app user can select multiple items and i stored items in

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> All;
```

and my HashMap values look like this

```
Key:Name, Value:[Quantity, Default-Price, Total_price, position]
    Key: Trouser, Value: [2, 8, 16, 3]
    Key: Shirt, Value: [3, 15, 45, 0]
    Key: Coat, Value: [2, 7, 14, 2]
    Key: Pants, Value: [3, 10, 30, 1]
```

So,my problem is how can i post these items to server.i am new in android so please help me.

here is my AsyncTask

```
public static class AddItemDB extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            All = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.DryMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.IronMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.WashMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.WashIronMap);

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> item : All.entrySet()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < All.size(); i++) {

                    String URL = "http://.com/mis/Laundry/insert_cart.php?" + "p_name=" + All.get(i) + "&p_quantity=" + item.getValue().get(0) +
                            "&p_price=" + item.getValue().get(1) + "&r_id=2&c_id=1&ct_id=1";

                    jParser.makeServiceCall(URL, JSONParser.POST);


                }

            }

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressLint({"ShowToast", "LongLogTag"})
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Log.d("Mission Successfulllll...............", "");
        }
    }
```

When i try above code i can not get proper data in database.

Comment: Don't use for loop for asynch it will consume your mobile data & battery.  try to pass all data once by create json & sever side parsing of json that is much easier & good.  String URL = "http://.com/mis/Laundry/insert_cart.php?jsondata="+ jsonobjet/ Array

Comment: Yes I tried without for loop,but how can I get hasmap keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code hope this work

```
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> iterator = All.entrySet().iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry = iterator.next();

                System.out.printf("Key : %s and Value: %s %n", entry.getKey(),
                        entry.getValue().get(0));

                String URL = "http://.com/mis/Laundry/insert_cart.php?" + "p_name=" + entry.getKey() + "&p_quantity=" + entry.getValue().get(0) +
                        "&p_price=" + entry.getValue().get(1) + "&r_id=2&c_id=1&ct_id=1";

                String jsonstr = jParser.makeServiceCall(URL, JSONParser.POST);

                iterator.remove(); // right way to remove entries from Map,
                // avoids ConcurrentModificationException

            }
```

Comment: Yes its working! exactly what i want, Thank you very much @arpit patel

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> All = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.DryMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.IronMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.WashMap);
            All.putAll(ListAdapter.WashIronMap);

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(ALL);
String URL = "http://.com/mis/Laundry/insert_cart.php?jsondata="+ object.toString();
jParser.makeServiceCall(URL, JSONParser.POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this !

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> All = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

        integers.add(2);
        integers.add(3);
        integers.add(4);
        integers.add(5);

        All.put("Trouser", integers);
        All.put("Shirt", integers);
        All.put("Coat", integers);
        All.put("Pants", integers);

        Log.e("mapString", All.toString());
```

String Log would be like below

```
{Trouser=[2, 3, 4, 5], Shirt=[2, 3, 4, 5], Coat=[2, 3, 4, 5], Pants=[2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

> So as a string you can send this to server, and there you can define
>   Parsing logic with keys !

Hope it will help you my friend !